# Magento 2 Mobile menu icon

Tags: magento2.3, menu, mobile, icon

I am trying to add an icon on Magento 2 mobile menu tab. How to add different icon in Magento 2 luma theme mobile menu (Menu & Account)

Answer (score 0):

you can add different icon by overriding your navigation less.

> theme\app\design\frontend\magento\Vendortheme\web\css\source Navigation.less

Replace your icon on below class.

```
.nav-toggle {
    .lib-icon-font(
        @icon-menu,
        @_icon-font-size: 28px,
        @_icon-font-color: @header-icons-color,
        @_icon-font-color-hover: @header-icons-color-hover
    );
}
```